# Characterisation of the rate distortion function: issue with functional derivative

Tags: information-theory, variational-analysis

In Elements of Information Theory, I can't figure out how the functional derivative $ \frac{\delta J}{\delta q(\hat{x}|x)} $ for $ J(q) = \sum_x \sum_{\hat{x}} p(x)q(\hat{x}|x)\log{\frac{q(\hat{x}|x)}{q(\hat{x})}} $  (from equation 10.119, ignoring the other terms of the expression which I have no problem with) leads to this result (equation 10.120, also ignoring non problematic terms):
$$ \frac{\delta J}{\delta q(\hat{x}|x)} = p(x)\log{\frac{q(\hat{x}|x)}{q(\hat{x})}} + p(x) - \sum_{x'}p(x')q(\hat{x}|x')\frac{1}{q(\hat{x})} p(x) $$

In particular, I can't see where the term with the sum over x' is coming from.

Comment: Don't forget that $q(\hat{x})$ is a function of $q(\hat{x}|x)$ as described in the book.

Comment: I know that $ q(\hat{x}) = \sum_x' q(\hat{x}|x')p(x') $ but I am not sure what to make of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a straightforward computation, only confusing only because of the notation with the variables $ x, \hat{x}, x' $. Spelling it out (only the last term):
$$
\frac{\delta}{\delta q(\hat{x}_0|x_0)} \left( \sum_{x,\hat{x}} p(x)q(\hat{x}|x)\log{q(\hat{x})} \right) = \sum_{x,\hat{x}} p(x)q(\hat{x}|x)\frac{1}{q(\hat{x})} \frac{\delta}{\delta q(\hat{x}_0|x_0) } q(\hat{x}) \\ =  \sum_{x,\hat{x},x'}  p(x)q(\hat{x}|x)\frac{1}{q(\hat{x})} \frac{\delta}{\delta q(\hat{x}_0|x_0) }  \left( q(\hat{x}|x') p(x')\right) \\
=  \sum_{x,\hat{x},x'}  p(x)q(\hat{x}|x)\frac{1}{q(\hat{x})} p(x') \; \delta_{x',x_0} \delta_{\hat{x}_0,\hat{x}}\\
=  \sum_{x}  p(x)q(\hat{x}_0|x)\frac{1}{q(\hat{x}_0)} p(x_0) 
$$
Setting $ x \rightarrow x', x_0 \rightarrow x, \hat{x}_0 \rightarrow x $ yields the correct term.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Slight detail but I think first line should be: $\frac{\delta}{\delta q(\hat{x_0}|x_0)}\left( \sum_{x,\hat{x}} p(x) q(\hat{x}|x) \log q( \hat{x} ) \right) = p(x) \log q(\hat{x}) + \sum_{x,\hat{x}}p(x)q(\hat{x}|x) \frac{1}{q(\hat{x})} \frac{\delta}{\delta q(\hat{x}_0|x_0)}q(\hat{x})$