# rate-distortion function: derivative of a functional

Tags: calculus-of-variations

My question concerns the answer on this post: [Characterisation of the rate distortion function: issue with functional derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3010199/characterisation-of-the-rate-distortion-function-issue-with-functional-derivati)

What do the symbols $\delta_{x',x_0}$ and $\delta_{\hat{x}_0,\hat{x}}$ mean; in particular, how is the third line derived from the second one?  Does anyone have a reference for these definitions/notation?  The Wikipedia article on functional derivatives doesn't seem to have them...Thank you.  (Sorry I couldn't comment on the post because I don't have enough reputation.)